# SI File transffering in XMPP in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, file-transfer

I am are working on file transfering in XMPP for iOS, please help to understand the basic difference between SI (XEP 0096) file Transfer and SOCKS 5 BYTE STREAM (XEP 0065).

Early we user SOCKS 5 BYTE STREAM (XEP 0065) and had success to some extent like it ask XMPP client spark for accepting the file that attempt to transfer but once clicking on accept button From Spark we get an issues like "item not found".

So after some analysis we are planed  to continue with SI file Transfer and also looking at XEP-0234: Jingle File Transfer, dont know which way to go with.

Please suggest which one should I choose and how to send and receive files with it.